# vectorize replacement over 3d for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I would like to vectorize (or optimize in any way possible), the following 3d *for* loop:

> dat: array with dim = c(n,n,m)
>
> ref: matrix with dim = c(n,m)

```
for(i in 1:length(dat[,1,1])){
    for(k in 1:length(dat[1,1,])){
        dat[i,,k][dat[i,,k] > ref[i,k]] <- NA 
    }
}
```

The array I am working with is `7e3` x `7e3` x `2e2` so the *for* loop above is impractically expensive. To boot, I will need to perform two or three very similar operations (on different arrays), so any saved time will be multiplied.

Example `dat` and `ref` arrays:

```
dat <- array(seq(1,75), dim=c(5,5,3))
ref <- cbind(seq(6,10), seq(36,40), seq(61,65))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this instead. It creates a `new_ref` array which is conformable to `dat`, so you can compare them directly:

```
new_ref <- aperm(array(ref, dim(dat)[c(1,3,2)]), c(1,3,2))

dat3 <- dat

dat3[dat3 > new_ref] <- NA
```

Comparison with your loop:

```
dat2 <- dat

for(i in 1:length(dat[,1,1])){
    for(k in 1:length(dat[1,1,])){
        dat2[i,,k][dat2[i,,k] > ref[i,k]] <- NA 
    }
}

identical(dat2, dat3)
#[1] TRUE
```